# Wpf Charting Toolkit Missing Time series values in Line Graph

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, toolkit

I am working on Wpf Charting Toolkit. There is a very basic problem which I am facing. I have done binding of my graph with a List which takes objects of KeyValuePair.

```
    List<KeyValuePair<DateTime,decimal>>
```

The list which I am providing contains few missing DateTime Values. Is there any possibility that graph can ignore those missing values and not show a long straight line where this gap occurs?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'missing DateTime values'?  Do you mean that there should normally be one value for every day (or some other regular interval), but sometimes there aren't?  For example, if you had points for each of March 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th and 6th, would March 4th be 'missing'?

Comment: Yes Luke that's exactly what I meant to say. Do you have any workable solution form this problem?

Comment: I assume that missing dates cause a gap in the chart line - is this correct?  If so, my first idea was to use `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` for the key, but that causes the charts to throw an ArgumentNullException.  Generally, the WPF (and Silverlight) Toolkit Charts are a bit limited in what they can do.  For basic stuff they are okay but once you start trying to do something a little less basic you quite quickly hit their limits.  Looking at using a third-party charting toolkit instead is probably your best bet here.

Comment: Luke I also tried using DateTime? but it didn't worked for me but thanks for replying.